# Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem:

After I login to my mysql database server using "mysql -u root -p" on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server everything seems to be OK, as I can login without a problem.
But then the problems start, as I would like to show using the examples below:

```
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `cloud`.* TO 'root'@'%'                  |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dentalfraeser24`.* TO 'root'@'%'        |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `joomla`.* TO 'root'@'%'                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host 'localhost'
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Connection id:      626
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         16 min 38 sec

mysql> SELECT user();
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| root@%         |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database test;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'test'
```

It looks like the system has some kind of split personality and sometimes thinks it is 'root'@'%' and other times 'root'@'localhost'.

The thing is, I cannot install anything mysql related anymore as no new database tables can be created. 
I must say that there was once Plesk installed on the server, which I removed, as I found it horrible.

Does anyone have a hint for a solution?

Comment: OK, I found it! As I already imagined, it was that pesky Plesk that was in my way! Plesk renames the administrative user to admin, so that is really the user you must login to if you want to change the permissions of any other user. After I logged into my mysql database using:
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow`
I was able to grant all privileges to my root user.
That did the trick!

Comment: You can add this as an answer!